# JQuery datepicker() by CSS class in ASP.net dynamically created TemplateFields

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, datepicker

I am using TemplateFields in a Gridview which creates textboxes dynamically as records are added to the Gridview. Since I cannot have ASP controls with the same ID's I cannot use ClientIDMode=Static for these controls.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="control-group">
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlDevMembers" runat="server" Height="100%" ScrollBars="None" Visible="true" Width="100%">
          <asp:GridView ID="grdDevSignoffs" runat="server" OnRowCommand="grdDevSignoffs_RowCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table-striped" cellspacing="30" GridLines="None" CellPadding="10" RowStyle-Height="40px" HorizontalAlign="Center" BorderStyle="None">

            <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Event" DataField="desc" ControlStyle-Width="100px"  />
            <asp:TemplateField ControlStyle-BorderStyle="None"  ControlStyle-BorderColor="Transparent" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Name">
             <ItemTemplate>
           <div style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;"><%#Eval("Lastname")%>, <%#Eval("FirstName")%></div>
           </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Signoff Date" HeaderStyle-BorderStyle="None" HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="0px" ControlStyle-Width="100px" 
                                            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                               <asp:textbox ID="txtDevDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SignOffDate") %>' CssClass="form-control input-sm datepick" Width="140" style="margin-left: 20px;margin-right: 20px;"/>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField ControlStyle-BorderStyle="None"  ControlStyle-BorderColor="Transparent" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSignoffDevUser" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-small btn-success" CommandName="signoffRecord" CommandArgument="<% CType(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex %>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Signoff</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp                            
                 </ItemTemplate>                    
               </asp:TemplateField>

                  <asp:TemplateField ControlStyle-BorderStyle="None"  ControlStyle-BorderColor="Transparent" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUndoSignoffDevUser" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-small btn-danger" CommandName="UndoRecordSignoff" CommandArgument="<% CType(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex %>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Undo Signoff</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp
                 </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
               <asp:TemplateField ControlStyle-BorderStyle="None"  ControlStyle-BorderColor="Transparent" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:LinkButton ID="btnRemoveDevUser" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-small btn-danger" CommandName="removeRecord" CommandArgument="<% CType(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex %>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                 </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
          </asp:GridView>
        </asp:Panel>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--end rw1col1-->
 </div>
```

So, I assigned the CSS class "form-control input-sm datepick" to these controls in the hopes that JQuery would trigger the datepicker function when the elements with these classes were clicked. However, for some reason, the JS isn't firing when using the class. This method works flawlessly when I test the same script against a control with a static ID so I'm fairly confident its not the structure of the JS.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.form-control input-sm datepick').each(function () {
            $(this).datepicker();
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Does anyone know how I can use this datepicker for dynamically created fields since ID's are generated at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$('body').on('focus', function(){
    $('.datepick').datepicker();
});​
```

Comment: I get a Javascript critical error: Invalid character using your snippet.

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.datepick').each(function () {
            $(this).datepicker();
        });
    });
```

Thank you javc91 for your help. your $(.datepick) bit is what made me realize I only needed to include items with that additional class rather than the whole "form-control input-sm datepick" class, which was causing the JS to not trigger based on that CSS class. Kudos.